# xcode 4.5.2 crashing if I am adding FacebookSDK.framework

Tags: xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I just add facebookSDK.framework in ios project. xcode keep crashing just after attaching the app. 
Even I am not able to run facebooksdk 3.1 samples. xcode crashing but samples are attaching to simulator successfully. As I am able to run it on simulator after xcode crash. please help

Comment: `XCode` usually does not crash due to even hundreds of errors in code. Check your system for background processes eating up the resources. Something is making XCode hung up.

Comment: Are the samples running fine in simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these steps :
Installing Facebook sdk [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) see the video --

Configure app and get the App Id from Facebook

Start Xcode project -- 
Drag and Drop the Framework folder in the project framework folder
Add Resource Bundle also  (and Version -- A -- DeprecatedHeaders)

Check three frameworks -- 
Account, Add Support, and Social framework's
Check
Build Setting -- other Linker Flags (Double click it ) "-sqlite3.0"

Set Facebook app id in app configuration --
in supporting file in the project-name.plist file of the project -- add a new row
Facebook AppId -- string value and enter the app id 
URL Types -- Add URL Scheme(Array) -- Item 0 (string)  -- fbAppId (App ID and prefix with fb)

Let me know if you did all the steps and still if it does not worked...

Comment: He said he is not able to run the `facebook sdk 3.1` sample codes with XCode open. Its not that he is getting errors, his `XCode` is crashing instead.